# Jpa Entity Manager :changes not taken into account

Tags: java, jpa

i have a batch that updates entities from another database , i use the same entityManager as the one used in the main application , but i can't see changes in my entities , until i restart TomcatServer  .

Comment: Could you show the relevant bits of code?

Comment: which technologies are you using. are you using spring. which jpa implementation are u using. can you provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

EntityManager is not aware about bulk operations. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told with following words:

> Caution should be used when executing bulk update or delete operations
>   because they may result in inconsistencies between the database and
>   the entities in the active persistence context. In general, bulk
>   update and delete operations should only be performed within a
>   transaction in a new persistence context or before fetching or
>   accessing entities whose state might be affected by such operations.

What you can do is refreshing single entities via [EntityManager.refresh(Object entity)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29)